# Nuget server on IIS7 / Win2008 faults w3wp.exe

Tags: iis-7, fault, w3wp, nuget-server

I realize this is borderline non-development, but I'm a developer trying to create a NuGet Server, not an IIS guy, so hopefully someone here has experienced this.

I have some libraries used across several applications, so I wanted to make NuGet packages out of them. I also wanted to set up a proper NuGet server so that people collaborating with me would have easy access, and to ease the integration with the CI side (pushing new packages from TeamCity builds). I followed the instructions here, starting at "Creating Remote Feeds":

http://docs.nuget.org/docs/creating-packages/hosting-your-own-nuget-feeds

I followed it to the letter, of course using the latest version of the NuGet.Server package available as of writing. It worked fine on my dev box using VS2010, so I deployed it to the live server (Win2008, IIS7). The app pool is running .Net in Integrated mode, the app is running using the NetworkService identity, and I gave full rights on the designated packages directory to the Network Service account.

Then when I try to access the site, I immediately get this error in the Application event viewer:

Faulting application w3wp.exe, version 7.0.6001.18000, time stamp 0x47919ed8, faulting module ntdll.dll, version 6.0.6001.18538, time stamp 0x4cb73957, exception code 0xc0000374, fault offset 0x00000000000a7857, process id 0xa8c, application start time 0x01cc9f77f1f23af0.

The web server is running many other web applications, most of them ASP.NET MVC, so in general it should be fine.

How would someone not very knowledgeable on IIS go about finding out what causes this fault? I don't have an IIS admin to lean on, so the developer has to play IT guy. :|

Answer (score 0):

If `ntdll.dll` is faulting, something is badly wrong. I would try again with the latest version of NuGet Gallery - there have been many changes recently.

The docs online at nuget.org are a bit out of date. We followed the details here, which worked pretty much first time:

http://www.codecapers.com/post/How-to-Set-Up-a-Local-NuGet-Gallery.aspx